# In R Shiny, is it possible to select a group of check boxes by click-and-dragging over them?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, jquery-ui-selectable

### Problem

I want to represent a 6x8 grid of check boxes that have the same input ID. To save time, I want to be able to select multiple check boxes at once by holding 'click' and dragging over my intended selection.

### Attempted ideas so far

This may require javascript, or something like jqui_selectable(), however I haven't been able to make these work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first step. [Source](https://codepen.io/lancebush/pen/GqoGjd).

Unfortunately, that doesn't work with Shiny checkboxes. So I added a click listener of the checkboxes in the JavaScript file but it doesn't work, I have no idea why.

R code:

```r
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "checkboxes.js"),
    tags$link(href = "checkboxes.css", rel = "stylesheet")
  ),
  br(),
  h3("Left-click and drag to select."),
  h3("Right-click and drag to deselect."),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("checked"),
  br(),
  
  tags$div(
    class = "checkboxes",
    tags$label(
      tags$input(type = "checkbox", id = "checkboxA"),
      tags$span("A")
    ),
    br(),
    tags$label(
      tags$input(type = "checkbox", id = "checkboxB"),
      tags$span("B")
    ),
    br(),
    tags$label(
      tags$input(type = "checkbox", id = "checkboxC"),
      tags$span("C")
    ),
    br(),
    tags$label(
      tags$input(type = "checkbox", id = "checkboxD"),
      tags$span("D")
    ),
    br(),
    tags$label(
      tags$input(type = "checkbox", id = "checkboxE"),
      tags$span("E")
    ),
    br(),
    tags$label(
      tags$input(type = "checkbox", id = "checkboxF"),
      tags$span("F")
    )
  ),
  
  br(),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["checked"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["checkboxA"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Files **checkboxes.js** and **checkboxes.css**, to put in the ***www*** subfolder of the app:

```js
var sx;
var sy;
var ex;
var ey;
var ta;
var drag = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var dragArea = document.createElement("div");
  dragArea.setAttribute("class", "dragArea");
  document.body.appendChild(dragArea);
  
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
    alert("checkbox clicked"); // this never happens!
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
    Shiny.setInputValue(id, checked);
  });
});

document.oncontextmenu = function() {
  return false;
};

$(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  if(drag) {
    var flipX = "";
    var flipY = "";
    var top = sy;
    var left = sx;
    var height = event.pageY - sy;
    var width = event.pageX - sx;

    if(event.pageX - sx < 0) {
      flipX = "scaleX(-1)";
      width = sx - event.pageX;
      left = event.pageX;
    }

    if(event.pageY - sy < 0) {
      flipY = "scaleY(-1)";
      height = sy - event.pageY;
      top = event.pageY;
    }

    $(".dragArea").attr(
      "style",
      "display:block; top:" +
        top +
        "px;  left:" +
        left +
        "px; width:" +
        width +
        "px; height: " +
        height +
        "px; transform:" +
        flipX +
        " " +
        flipY +
        ";"
    );
  }
});

$(document).on("mousedown", function(event) {
  drag = true;
  sx = event.pageX;
  sy = event.pageY;

  switch(event.which) {
    case 1:
      //Left Mouse button pressed.
      $(".dragArea").addClass("add");
      $(".dragArea").removeClass("remove");
      break;
    case 3:
      //Right Mouse button pressed.
      $(".dragArea").addClass("remove");
      $(".dragArea").removeClass("add");
      break;
    default:
    //do nothing
  }
  
  $(".dragArea").attr(
    "style",
    "display:block; top:" +
      event.pageY +
      "px; left:" +
      event.pageX +
      "px; width:0; height:0;"
  );
  
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function(event) {
  drag = false;
  $(".dragArea").attr("style", "display:none;");

  ex = event.pageX;
  ey = event.pageY;

  if(ex < sx) {
    ta = ex;
    ex = sx;
    sx = ta;
  }

  if(ey < sy) {
    ta = ey;
    ey = sy;
    sy = ta;
  }
  
  switch(event.which) {
    case 1:
      //Left Mouse button pressed. Check
      selectItems(true);
      break;
    case 3:
      //Right Mouse button pressed. Uncheck
      selectItems(false);
      break;
    default:
    //do nothing
  }
  
});

function selectItems(checked) {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    var cxLow = pos.left;
    var cxHi = pos.left + $(this).width();
    var cyLow = pos.top;
    var cyHi = pos.top + $(this).height();
    if(cxLow <= sx && sx <= cxHi && cxLow <= ex && ex <= cxHi) {
      if(cyLow <= sy && sy <= cyHi && cyLow <= ey && ey <= cyHi) {
        $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
      }
    } else if(sx <= cxHi && ex >= cxLow) {
      if(sy <= cyHi && ey >= cyLow) {
        $(this).prop("checked", checked);
      }
    }

  });
}
```

```css
.dragArea {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.dragArea.remove {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.dragArea.add {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.15);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.05);
}
```

[image]